# Multivariable Calculate $\int\int_D(x^2 + y^2 )dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

Calculate Double integral $$\iint_D (x^2 + y^2 ) dxdy$$ 
where:
$$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x\le x^2+y^2\le2x, -x\le y \le x \}$$
**What i did?**
I tried to use polar coordinates and i got this ==> $\sqrt x\le r \le \sqrt(2x)$

> Can you please help me with the limit of integration if i change this
>   to polar coordinates. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't fully used polar coordinates. Recall the transformation is given by $(x,y) \mapsto (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. From $D$ we then get the bounds: $r\cos \theta \leq r^2 \leq 2 r\cos \theta$, $-r \cos \theta \leq r\sin \theta \leq r \cos \theta$. The first one of course reduces to $\cos \theta \leq r \leq 2\cos \theta$ while if you divide the second one by $r\cos\theta$ you can get $\arctan(-1) \leq \theta \leq \arctan(1)$. From there you get an integral that is manageable to evaluate.

Comment: so the integral will be like that ==  $$\iint_E (r^3cos^2phi + r^3sin^2phi ) drdphi$$ ?

Comment: Yes, but also recall the identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$.

Comment: Yea exactly so now only r^3 we have
$$\iint_E (r^3) drdphi$$

Comment: Yup. The bounds are kind of annoying but the integral is not too bad to compute.

Comment: the answer will be 4.0839 ? :) thank you for the help ur a real hero